# Where does the AWS EFS backup get stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, aws-backup

I am backing up my EFS using AWS Backup service. Wanted to know where the Backup is actually stored? Is this getting stored in the EFS itself or not? I noticed a huge hike in the data stored in the EFS so wanted to know if the automated backup can be causing this hike or not, I tried deleting few backup recovery points from the backup vault but is not making much of a difference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backups are not stored on your EFS itself. They are stored in `Recovery points` in a `backup vault`. Term `Recovery point` is interchangeable with `backup` according to [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/recovery-points.html) docs.
you need to check you application etc which stores data on efs or check efs itself what has been added which has caused this hike.

Comment: thanks for the inputs I wanted to confirm that the backup was not the reason for this hike.

Answer (score 0):

EFS Automatic backups and Regular EFS Backups are stored in different Backup Vaults.
The EFS Automatic backup vaults are stored in `aws/efs/automatic-backup-vault` vault.

By default you won't be able to delete the EFS Automatic Backup Recovery Points from `aws/efs/automatic-backup-vault` vault since the `Access policy` is set to deny deletions.

If you want to disable EFS Automatic Backups and delete those recovery points you can follow this document:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/efs-disable-automatic-backups/